# localhost/phpmyadmin giving page not found error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I'm running wampserver.

I had a mysql server crash, and the wampmysqld service would not start up. Also, `localhost/phpmyadmin` did not show phpmyadmin but gave me a 403 error. I installed the mysql-addon for another mysql version. Then I went to the wampserver icon and did Mysql > Version > and selected the add-on version I'd just downloaded.

This helped, wampmysqld was able to start up, the wampserver icon was able to go green all the way, and my application is working. However, phpmyadmin is giving a 404 error. How do I fix this?

`phpmyadmin.conf` is:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/" 

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
#        Order Deny,Allow
#   Deny from all
#   Allow from 127.0.0.1
#
# by
#
#        Order Allow,Deny 
#   Allow from all
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

I changed `c:/` to `d:/` as per the location of phpmyadmin on my machine and restarted all services. But I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 10):

You need to configure your apache2.conf to make phpMyAdmin works.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line to the end of the file.

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: it worked for me in 2022

Answer (score 0):

Start wamp or xamp  make sure the icon color change to green for wamp. This time open it in another browsers not Internet explorer . it should work

Answer (score 0):

When you install a new phpmyadmin, or anything at all that refreshes the state of the apache.conf, there is usually need to retrace all previous manual inclusions in the config file.

Hence, given that when phpmyadmin is installed like in [this](https://geekrewind.com/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-linux-with-apache/) tutorial, you added a line in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` it becomes necessary to repeat that step:

Hence, running the command

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and the including the following line at the end of the opened config file

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

usually solves this problem.

Remember to hit `CTRL+O` to save your changes, and then `CTRL+X` to close the open file.

Lastly, restart apache to let your new configuration take effect:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

That's it!